# dynamically open accordion based on case statment

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to select what accordion has the `.active` class set based on the results of a switch/case statement.

I currently have a switch/case statement set to hide tabs depending on the statement.

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#accordion-test").accordion({
                collapsible: true,
                active: '#accordion-test .active'

            });
        });
    </script>

<div id="accordion-test">
    <h3 class="content1 one">Content Title</h3>

    <div align="left">
        <p>Content for 1 Goes Here</p>
    </div>
    <h3 class="two">Content Title</h3>

    <div align="left">
        <p>Content for 2 Goes Here</p>
    </div>
    <h3 class="active three">Content Title</h3>

    <div align="left">
        <p>Content for 3 Goes Here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The statement**

the session varible is set to one, two or three

```
      <?php
            switch ($_SESSION['session']) {

                    case "one":
                        ?>
                        <style type="text/css">
                            .two,.three {
                                display: none !important;
                            }
                        </style>
                        <?php
    break;
                    case "one":
                        ?>
                        <style type="text/css">
                            .two,.three {
                                display: none !important;
                            }
                        </style>
                        <?php
break;
                    case "two":
                        ?>
                        <style type="text/css">
                            .one,.three {
                                display: none !important;
                            }
                        </style>
                        <?php
    case "three":
                        ?>
                        <style type="text/css">
                            .one,.two{
                                display: none !important;
                            }
                        </style>
}
                        <?php
```

with this statement I can show or hide accordion tabs depending on the variable present `one`,`two` or `three`.

I would now like to make the displayed accordion tab active,

**for example**

```
case "one":
                        ?>
                        <style type="text/css">
                            .two,.three {
                                display: none !important;
                            }

HAVE ACTIVE STATE APPLIED TO ACCORDION TAB ONE
                        </style>
                        <?php


   <?php
    case "three":
                        ?>
                        <style type="text/css">
                            .one,.two{
                                display: none !important;
                            }
HAVE ACTIVE STATE APPLIED TO ACCORDION TAB THREE
                        </style>
                        <?php
```

Comment: Could you please explain with a code example

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code? I have no idea what the source of the switch is (variable name etc).

Comment: the source of the switch is a POST getting one, two or three depending on what button clicked. ill add code

Comment: Added simple example below. You can customise to suit your needs

Comment: thanks reading through now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to bypass using accordion to make its selections and overriding it with styles. That is fighting against the way it should work (using accordion). Instead of generating styles dynamically, just tell the accordion which tab to open at startup.

Here is an example that avoids any server-side generation of styles: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/d6mSA/1187/

```
$(function() {
  var $accordion = $("#accordion");
  $accordion.accordion({
    autoHeight: true,
    collapsible: true
  });
  // Open the selected tab from the element
  $accordion.accordion('activate', $accordion.data("selection"));
});
```

It just picks up a `data-` attribute with the current selection number in it and tells the accordion to open that one:

```
 <div id="accordion" data-selection="2">
```

Or even simpler, just set the active value from the `data-`:

```
$(function() {
  var $accordion = $("#accordion");
  $accordion.accordion({
    autoHeight: true,
    collapsible: true,
    active:  $accordion.data("selection")
  });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/d6mSA/1188/

Comment: I understand what you are saying about hiding the accordion section with css, its messy and not efficient. with the function above how can I set the accordion tabs to show and what one to open depending on the case/switch statement ? .

Comment: Your switch is just a string number at the moment "one", "two", "three". Where does that come from as you really just want the index (0, 1, 2 etc) to select a tab. Where does your selection come from as text numbers are not usually found in the wild :)

Comment: the statement represents a variable  that is the current session, the session can be either one, two or three. if three selected show tab 3 in accordion only and have it open.

Comment: So change your variable to use values of 0, 1 & 2 instead. Much simpler than names of numbers. (or, worst case, have a small switch that converts the names to numbers)

Comment: ok, but regardless of this, how do I change the data-selection="?" depending on the variable present in the session

Comment: Basic PHP injection: `<div id="accordion-test" data-selection="<?php $_SESSION['session']?>">`. Much simpler. You can throw away all that style generating code

Comment: ahh there we go, perfect. thank you ill give this a go and accept answer when i get it working, and yes. i get what you mean by cleaner